# MongoDB pymongo - update primary key

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have an existing collection which contains 30m of data.

At the moment, its primary key is default ObjectId but now I'd like to add another primary key to it due to performance and identification issues.

My research comes out with a solution of removing and inserting data all over again with a new primary key.

I couldn't find any other info about simply adding a new primary key to existing database, wondering if this is not available feature in pymongo?

I'm worried that this whole operation will cause a issues as the database is quite big and will be hard to recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not have the concept of "primary key".

Each document must have the _id field set and the _id values must be unique in a collection. You can't change this behavior.

You can add additional unique indexes but they wouldn't replace the _id requirements just outlined.

You are also misusing the "primary key" concept even in relational sense. There can be only one primary key in a table, hence a primary key cannot be "added".

Comment: perfect - cleared up the concepts. thank you!